# How to locate elements by their innerText in Selenium - Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to locate and click on buttons by using their "innerText' (in my case: 'Sprint 1', 'Sprint 2', and 'Sprint 3')

Here is a part of my html:

```
<div class="show dropdown">
    <div class="dropdown-menu show">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-item active" role="button">
            <div class="period-title">
                <span><span class="badge badge-success">active</span><span class="abc-name">Sprint 1</span></span>
            </div>
        </a>
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-item" role="button">
            <div class="period-title">
                <span><span class="badge badge-info">future</span><span class="abc-name">Sprint 2</span></span>
            </div>
        </a>
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-item" role="button">
            <div class="period-title">
                <span><span class="badge badge-info">future</span><span class="abc-name">Sprint 3</span></span>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

and this is one of my tries that fails: (error message: "... is not a valid XPath expression)

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[contains(text(), 'Sprint 1'")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its failed due to syntax error.

Try this:

```
//span[contains(.,'Sprint 1')]
```

OR

```
//span/text()[contains(.,'Sprint 1')]
```

Thanks.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

To click on dynamic element you need to induce `WebDriverWait`() and wait for `element_to_be_clickable`() and following xpath.

```
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//span[text()='Sprint 1']"))).click()
```

You need to import below libraries.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```